# Can't upgrade VirtualBox in Mint 12

Tags: linux-mint, apt, virtualbox

I'm running Linux Mint 12 x64 and can't get the latest virtualbox-4.1 update through apt.

I have the following line in my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian oneiric contrib
```

Launching VirtualBox (currently at v4.1.6) shows an alert that a new version (v4.1.20) is available. Visiting the [Packages file](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/oneiric/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) on the repo page shows v4.1.20 as the currently available version.

I can only assume a conflict or missing dependency exists somewhere, but I've no idea where to start looking for it.

Apt doesn't report any failures on the repos, or that virtualbox is being held back.

Comment: Show the output of `apt-cache policy virtualbox-4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new VirtualBox package is called virtualbox-4.2. Therefore, if you have package `virtualbox-4.1` or `virtualbox` installed, it will not be shown as an update. Removing the installed version and installing the new one should work:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2` automatically removed virtualbox-4.1 - thanks!